# Can we use Salesforce Data in Multi Org BU Connectors?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

We have multiple BU's, some that are a child of other BU's, we are trying to build a region-based structure (e.g. Europe > Germany, Europe > France, NA > USA)

Using the Multi Org connector we plan to have some of these BU's connected, for instance our "NA" CRM org will be connected to the "NA" MC BU. What I would like to know is whether we can still use Salesforce connected features within the "USA" BU? What I mean by this is the features like "Salesforce Data" entry and "Send tracking back to Salesforce" if the connected org is connected to the parent BU and not the child directly.

Answer (score 1):

No, the child BU can't use the parent BU's connected CRM org in Salesforce Data entry events, and can't send tracking back to that org. The main purpose of BUs is to limit the access of data between teams so allowing this functionality would be risky. You can still build segments off the Synchronized DEs and share these across BUs.

Comment: To add to Baneen's comment, in Multi-Org configuration, Child BUs for the sake of connecting to Sales Cloud(s) act as their own accounts, so they don't inherit any configurations or mappings from their parents. You can also find this information in FAQ: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_faqs_for_multi_org.htm&type=5

Comment: So could we technically just connect the same CRM org to the child business unit as well?